# how to use for loop to create a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I made 150 vectors and I called them c1,c2,...,c150 now I want to make a dataframe with them. is there a easy way to not write 150 vectors by hand like this:

```
  data<-data.frame(c1,c2,c3,...,c150)
```

writing 150 vectors in the above bracket is frustrating

Comment: While not your question, I suspect making the 150 vectors in the first place was unnecessary. For instance, if they were made using a loop, you may have been better off using `lapply` or something similar to generate them in a `list`. Then the conversion to a `data.frame` would be just `as.data.frame(listname)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `mget` to get all the vectors in a list and then wrap it in `data.frame`

```
data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "c\\d+")))

#   c1 c2
#1   1 11
#2   2 12
#3   3 13
#4   4 14
#5   5 15
#6   6 16
#7   7 17
#8   8 18
#9   9 19
#10 10 20
```

**data**

```
c1 <- 1:10
c2 <- 11:20
```

Comment: how it picked all c1 to c150?

Comment: @shere - `"c\\d+"` is a regular expression looking for `c` followed by any repeat of the digits `0-9`.

Comment: I get this error: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10000, 28368, 26465, 1

Comment: @shere - your `c1`-`c150` vectors aren't all the same length I think. They need to all be the same length so they can fit in a rectangular `data.frame`.

Comment: but they are all the same, all of them are multiplication of columns of same matrix

Comment: @shere Can you confirm if `lengths(mget(ls(pattern = "c\\d+")))` return the same values for all ?

Comment: then there must be some other vectors which must be included in the pattern. Maybe this will help `data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "^c\\d+$")))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
data.frame(mget(paste0("c", 1:150)))
```